# Appending to pointer slice

Tags: go, pointers, append, slice

Go is my first programming language and I am trying to learn about pointers by writing a program that organizes information based on taxonomies. I'm having some trouble understanding how to append to a pointer slice.

```
type List struct {
    Taxonomies []Taxonomy
}

func (l *List) Add(t Taxonomy) {
    var exists bool
    var existing *Taxonomy
    for _, taxonomy := range l.Taxonomies {
        if taxonomy.Name == t.Name {
            exists = true
            existing = &taxonomy
        }
    }
    if exists {
        for _, term := range t.Data {
            termExists := false
            for _, existingTerm := range existing.Data {
                if existingTerm.Name == term.Name {
                    termExists = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if termExists {
                continue
            }
            (*existing).Data = append((*existing).Data, term)
        }
    } else {
        l.Taxonomies = append(l.Taxonomies, t)
    }
}

type Taxonomy struct {
    Name string
    Data []Term
}

type Term struct {
    Name, Link string
}
```

I think the problem is toward the bottom, this line:

```
(*existing).Data = append((*existing).Data, term)
```

By following the code in a debugger, I can see that the taxonomy stored in the "existing" variable is being updated when the append occurs, but the data is not updated in the actual List.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The dereference there is not needed, this is the same as writing `existing.Data = append(existing.Data, term)`. `Data` is updated, so what are you referring to as the "actual list"? It would probably help to make this a [mre] showing exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.

I think I don't understand how pointers work in this scenario. I have a reference to some Taxonomy struct stored in the variable "existing", and I intend for the Data property on that Taxonomy to be updated when I append to existing.Data -- however, it appears that only that Data property on existing is modified. I will work on a better example.

Comment: oh "actual list" is `l.Taxonomies`? You are copying the `Taxonomy` value, so you are only updating the copy. It doesn't matter if `existing` is a pointer when it's a pointer to a local copy.

Comment: Hello again.

I still don't fully understand, but that is on me. I will continue looking at it until it makes sense. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://go.dev/play/p/89mf-eoQKOq) do what you want? (another option is to use `Taxonomies []*Taxonomy`, which is probably most people's default to start with)

Comment: It does! that works as I expected. And after seeing an example I can actually understand why my code was wrong. Thank you very much for teaching me.

If you want to post this as an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.Taxonomies` is a `[]Taxonomy`, so the `taxonomy` value is going to be a copy of the element, and changes to that copy will not be reflected in the original `List` value.

You can iterate using the index to avoid copying the value

```
for i := range l.Taxonomies {
    if l.Taxonomies[i].Name == t.Name {
        exists = true
        existing = &l.Taxonomies[i]
    }
}
```

However that still leaves the possibility of copying the data passed to methods like `Append`. Instead it's probably better to use pointers throughout:

```
type List struct {
    Taxonomies []*Taxonomy
}

func (l *List) Add(t *Taxonomy) {
...
```